# Assigning char * to another char *

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct

I have an array of `struct` pointers, inside each `struct` is another `struct` which contains a field named `firstname`, firtstname is a `char *.` The `struct`s are filled with data from a file when the program first runs to form a linked list. My definitions are below...

```
struct person 
{
  char *firstname;
  char *lastname;
};

struct node
{
  struct person employee;
  struct node *next;
};

struct node *nodes[MAX_NODES];
```

I get a string input from the user and store it in a char * (which points to the same size memory block as the original), now I want to chage the char * that is accessed by

```
nodes[index]->data.firstname
```

to the char * I just read in from the user. I tried

```
nodes[index]->data.firstname = newinput;
```

Tested the above with a printf() and it seemed to have worked, however printing out the data at a later stage prints the old data. Why is this?

Comment: Short Answer: use `strcpy()`

Comment: maybe the buffer pointed by `newinput` gets changed ?

Comment: @clcto Great, does that mean I need to modify my program to make `firstname` a char array?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you have two pointers that point to the same block of memory.

You probably want to allocate additional memory for the copied string using `malloc()`, and then copy the original string to that new block of memory using `strcpy()` or `strncpy()`.

Comment: The new string was indeed giving its own memory from `malloc`. I thought I could simply assign a pointer to another pointer. From my understanding, if each pointer is of the same type that is legal. But obviously its not fully correct since my code doesn't work properly.

Comment: @CSStudent: It is legal to assign a pointer to another pointer. But that just creates two pointers to the same data. It doesn't copy the data. So if you later write over that data, it changes for both pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Since the array does not change to a new value unexpectedly, but *reverts* to an "old" one, I think the problem is in fact by-value parameter passing.

You'd be passing an instance of your struct to a function and modify its `firstname` pointer inside. Then, it (obviously) has the right value inside the rest of the function, but does no more once the function exited.

The solution would be to pass a pointer to your structure. The pointer gets copied inside the function, and both copy naturally point to the same object, which you can then modify from within the function.

```
void changeByVal(struct person person) {
    person.firstname = malloc(FIRST_NAME_LEN);
    strcpy(person.firstname, "John Doe");
}

void changeByPtr(struct person *person) {
    person->firstname = malloc(FIRST_NAME_LEN);
    strcpy(person->firstname, "John");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct person p1, p2;

    p1.firstname = "Jane";

    changeByVal(p1);
    changeByref(p2);

    // Prints "We have Jane and John" instead of "John and John"
    printf("We have %s and %s", p1.firstname, p2.firstname);
}
```

Comment: It does seem that way, however I declared all the structs as global variables so I don't actually pass them around via parameters. Thank you for the answer though :)

Comment: Oh well... I'm curious how you managed to get this behaviour though.

Comment: I can send you the source if you like. Its about 700 lines.

Comment: It would be easier to send you my github repo for the project. However I don't really want to post the link to it so everyone can view it. Can I send you a private message on stackoverflow?

Comment: Seems that SO doesn't have PMing. Just send it to ferasourcil@gmail.com then :)

Comment: Its been sent :) I use `gcc` as my compiler, with only the `-o` flag.